# Changing the before_filter to not require password for profile edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I want to let signed-in users change profile information on their edit page but not have to enter their password to do so, as they currently do, how could I effectively change this in the UsersController?

UsersController:

```
    before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:show, :new, :create]
    before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
    before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy



    def edit
       @title = "Edit user"
    end

    def update
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
          redirect_to @user
      else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
   end
 end
```

Edit Page

```
     </div>
     <h1> Confirm Password</h1><br /><br />
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password, "Enter Password" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
   </div>
   <% end %>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. If you are authenticating their username and password at login, they shouldn't have to re-enter their password to edit their profile page. After login, it should persist. Are you using any authentication gems?

Comment: Hm, not that I know of. Just, in my edit (update) page, I have the form for confirming password upon image upload and it doesn't work unless the password is entered and correct.

Comment: Very odd, I'd rewrite you're authentication. It's very impractical use of authenticating. Have a look at [Rails Tutorial Sessions](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top) and use that as a paragon.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your User model, if you are using devise gem:

```
def update_with_password(params={})
  if current_user && self.password.blank?
    false
    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: If I'm not using any authentication gems could I still accomplish a user edit without having to verify the password?

Comment: Yes, why not? Just check to see if the password is blank and don't do any type of checking on it before the update_attributes.

Comment: Where are you trying to check to see if the password is filled out correctly?

Comment: Where is the authenticate function? Where did you get it?

Comment: Hi Eric,  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy] In my UsersController

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it in a project that I am working right now:

**User model**:

```
validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 8, :maximum => 20}, :unless => Proc.new { |u| u.password_optional? or u.password.blank? }
  validates :password, :confirmation => true, :unless => Proc.new { |u| u.password_optional? }
```

This method will depend on the password logic you have...But mine looks like this:

```
def password_optional?
    optional = (encrypted_password.present? && password.blank? && password_changing.blank?)
    optional
  end
```

**User Controller**
In any action that you want the password to be optional, do the following:
(Assuming you have an @user object...)

```
@user.password_optional = true
```

I assume this would be in your **update** action.